How to modify this equation to maintain the law of conservation of mass?
I am trying to determine the mass yields based on this equation:
$$woodchip (CH_{1.45}O_{0.66}) → 0.127char + 0.107CO_2 + 0.211CO + 0.237H_2O+0.16H_2 + 0.106CH_4 + 0.029C_2H_4 + 0.0516 Tar$$
Tar is defined as a combination of benzene, toluene, and naphthalene with relative fractions of 64.6%, 12.6%, and 22.8% respectively. The composition of char is to be determined from the residual mass fractions. However, when I checked for the law of conservation of mass, I observed that hydrogen is in excess on the products side even without considering char. So, how do I rebalance the stoichiometric coefficients?

how did you get those numbers? did you make a typing error?

I got the numbers from a research paper: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.enconman.2023.117812
I just used the exact values as provided

If you simply substitute $Tar = (0.646C_6H_6 + 0.126C_7H_8 + 0.228C_{10}H_8)$ then I get the RHS to be $0.127 C_{char} + 0.845C$ for carbon and $0.127H_{char} + 1.680H$ for hydrogen which, as you say, doesn't add up. However, I can't see the paper specify that the composition of the tar is in molar quantities. The 64.6%/12.6%/22.8% may be mass fractions in which case you'll have to calculate the molar fractions... It looks like this is hinted at in the supplementary material.

Thanks for your reply. I will try it

@GeoffreyLiddell, I have tried as you said, however, I still get the same result. Upon converting the tar composition to molar fractions, I got these values: 0.72441, 0.11978, and 0.15581 for C6H6, C7H8, and C10H8 respectively. However, even after that, I get 0.127H_char + 1.67H
